# Angular 5 - RouterLink on ngOnInit event

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When I click on this button it goes to a certain page:

```
<button routerLink="/mypage">Click Here</button>
```

What I want to do it to add this to add it to the ngOnInit:

```
 ngOnInit() {
  // Code to do the same as routerLink here
}
```

Can this be done? If so how?

Comment: You've got an answer here, but I would really like to ask why you want to route driectly after initiating your component. It seems to me that this should be done by the router config, not the ngOnInit lifecycle of you component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple as hello

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router) {}
ngOnInit() { this.router.navigate('/mypage'); }
```

Although I advise you to use this notation instead :

```
ngOnInit() { this.router.navigate(['/mypage']); }
```

The array notation is more flexible than the string one.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to go to the certain route when one component loads it's OnInit.

```
constructor(private: Router) { }
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.navigate(['/mypage']);
}
```

You can write this, but make sure you have RouterModule imported in the module where this component will be used.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Router :

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private router: Router){}

ngOnInit() {
  // Code to do the same as routerLink here
  this.router.nvaigate(['/mypage']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `router.navigate`

```
this.router.nvaigate('mypage')
```

Make sure you have imported

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```